# Linearly independent quadratic forms vanishing on a finite set of points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

The question I am interested in can be summed up as follows: given positive integers $n,m,k$, how do we write down $m$ linearly independent quadratic forms $Q_1, \cdots, Q_m \in \mathbb{C}[x_0, \cdots, x_n]$ such that the common-zero locus

$$V = V_{Q_1, \cdots, Q_m} = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C}) : Q_i(\mathbf{x}) = 0 \text{ for all } 1 \leq j \leq m\}$$

has size exactly equal to $k$?

Clearly, we require $m \geq n$ in order for there to be any hope, since $V$ is a variety of co-dimension at most $m$ so when $m < n$ then $V$ has positive dimension and hence cannot be a finite set.

The two base cases I am considering are when $(n,m,k) = (2, 2, 4)$ and $(3,5,5)$. In the former case, any pair of linearly independent ternary quadratic forms will do: indeed, the intersection $V_{Q_1, Q_2}$ is a complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and consists of four points. When $(n,m,k) = (3,5,5)$ a beautiful construction gives that such a quintuple $(Q_1, \cdots, Q_5)$ is given by the set of $4 \times 4$ pfaffians of a $5 \times 5$ skew-symmetric matrix of linear forms in $x_0, \cdots, x_3$.

Certainly, one can construct such a family by looking at general quadratic forms in $n+1$ variables, which forms a $\binom{n+2}{2}$-dimensional space. Given points $\mathbf{y}^{(1)}, \cdots, \mathbf{y}^{(k)} \in \mathbb{P}^n$, we can then solve the equations $Q(\mathbf{y}^{(j)}) = 0$ in terms of the coefficients of $Q$ to obtain a subspace. However, this description is not satisfying for me since it depends, unlike in the previous two examples, on knowing the actual set of points.

Going back to the example of $(3,5,5)$, we note that fixing five points and then constructing the family of 5-tuples of quadrics vanishing on those five points gives a 25-dimensional space; indeed, each term in the 5-tuple $(Q_1, \cdots, Q_5)$ is sampled from a 5-dimensional space of quadratic forms. Any set of five points in general position is equivalent to the set $$\{[1: \cdots : 0], \cdots, [0 : \cdots : 1], [1 : \cdots : 1]\},$$
any by identifying the (matrix of) the homography from this set to our prescribed set we have 16 degrees of freedom. Since we can scale our quintuple of quadratic forms by any non-zero scalar without affecting anything, we have $25 - 1 + 16 = 40$ degrees of freedom total. Observe that this is equal to the number of degrees of freedom of a $5 \times 5$ skew-symmetric matrix of linear forms in four variables.

In the same vein, we can do the same calculation for the $(2,2,4)$ case: fixing four points, the space of quadrics that pass through them is two: a pair would give four degrees of freedom. Identifying the set of four points with its homography to a 'standard' set of points gives $3 \times 3 = 9$ degrees of freedom. Scaling reduces the number of degrees of freedom by one, giving $9 + 4 - 1 = 12$, which is of course the same as just choosing a pair of ternary quadratic forms.

If we consider $(n,m,k) = (4,9,6)$ then there should be $9 \times 9 - 1 + 25 = 105$ degrees of freedom.

One way to construct such a tuple would be again to consider pfaffians: if one takes a $6 \times 6$ skew-symmetric matrix consisting of linear forms in five variables, then taking $4 \times 4$ sub-pfaffians gives 15 quadratic forms all vanishing on six points, and typically one can choose 9 of them to be linearly independent. However, there are only $5 \times 15 = 75$ degrees of freedom associated with $6 \times 6$ skew-symmetric matrices of linear forms in five variables, so this cannot account for all possibilities.

Comment: In your $(4,9,6)$ example, just take your  points $p_1,\ldots ,p_6$ general, so that they form a projective frame; for appropriate coordinates, $p_1=(1,0,\ldots ,0), \ldots , p_5=(0,0,\ldots ,1)$, and $p_6= (1,1,\ldots ,1)$. The quadratic forms vanishing at the $p_i$  are the forms $\sum_{i<j}a_{ij}x_ix_j$ with $\sum a_{ij}=0$. They form  a 9-dimensional vector space, take any basis — for instance $(x_ix_j-x_0x_1)$ with $i<j$, $j>1$.

Comment: @abx yes I am aware of the construction you gave. I understand that in principle this gives you all such tuples, by letting $\text{GL}_5$ act on the tuple you constructed for example. However this is not the same as the $n = 2, 3$ cases I gave, which gives a parametrization which manifestly gives tuples which vanish simultaneously at the correct number of points.

Comment: I don't understand, the construction is perfectly explicit. Never mind.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question; perhaps it will be more clear what I want